# Where can I find the required IDs for Watson Dialog Service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-dialog

When I create createDialog () have an id response dialogue but I do not know where this condigo client_id and conversation_id. Where can I get this IDs?I do not know where to find them.

```
DialogService service = new DialogService();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("{username}","{password}");

Map params = new HashMap();
params.put(DialogService.DIALOG_ID, "{dialog_id}");
params.put(DialogService.CLIENT_ID, {client_id});
params.put(DialogService.INPUT, "Hi Hello");
params.put(DialogService.CONVERSATION_ID, {conversation_id});

Conversation conversation = service.converse(params);
System.out.println(conversation);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API reference documentation](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/dialog/api/v1/#converse), a new `conversation_id` and `client_id` will be issued if they are not specified.

So to start a conversation, you should omit the `conversation_id` and `client_id` parameters. They will be generated by the service and included in the response.

Then to continue the conversation, you should specify the assigned `conversation_id` and `client_id` in subsequent requests.